# Valuation of a complete field is $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I was studying the book Local Class field theory by Iwasawa. There it's written if $(k,v)$ is a complete field (by what I mean is $k$ is complete under $v$ topology given by valuation $v$ on $k$) then $v(k^*)=\mathbb{Z}$. Can anyone please explain why, I can't figure it out

[Here's what eating me..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiNA9.png)

Answer (score 3):

That's not true in general.

If $k=\Bbb Q_p$ and $v$ is the $p$-adic valuation, then $v(\Bbb Q_p^\times)=\Bbb Z$. But if $k=\hat{\Bbb C}_p$ the $p$-adic valuation is not discrete.

Comment: Can you please check my Edit ? I can't post picture in comment

Comment: He must be assuming that the valuation is discrete from the beginning. Given that, after renormalization you may assume that it takes values in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @NTlearner95. $\hat{\Bbb C}_p$ is complete by definition. Its valuation is non-discrete because it contains solutions of $x^n=p$ for all $n$ and the valuation of such an $x$ is $1/n$.

Comment: Iwasawa was a great mathematician, but just as even Homer nods, so even great mathematicians can be a bit imprecise at times.